# How to shift tree view column string on right side for Odoo

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, one2many

i Have problem related to UI. i want to shift sale order line tree view column string on right side. So, Is there any solution for this problem. I'm using Odoo 10.

I'm also attaching screenshot below related to problem.

PFA
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can try : style="text-align: right" on the field XML declaration

Comment: @CZoellner, i tried to solve this problem by 'widget' and 'type', but it only reflect by data only not upper string. I also want to shuffle tree column string on right side.

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET, i am tried your solution but changes not reflect.

Comment: @CZoellner, i also applied style and custom css class, but changes not reflected.

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA it should be possible with less or css changes, but with a big side effect: every Odoo tree view will look the same, not only the one in sale order lines.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. It's work with  .th {text-align: right;} in css file. But, it impact complete system.

Comment: @CZoellner So, Have you any alternative solution?

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA not really